# How to include generic parameter in ILogger.Category

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, logging, .net-core-logging

**When** `TCategoryName` of `ILogger<TCategoryName>` is a generic type

**Then** how do I include type name of the generic parameter type in the category name?

E.g.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

class Foo<T> { }

using var services = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging(options => options.AddConsole())
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var logger1 = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Foo<string>>>();
logger1.LogInformation("test"); //writes info: Foo[0], but I want Foo[System.String]
```

Comment: Just some nitpicking: From your example/comment you rather want the generic parameter Type, not the name (because then you'd get `Foo[T]`). Note that the `[0]` is actually the event ID you give to your logging call (since you use the overload which does not accept an event ID, you get 0). I think you'd have to use a custom formatter. Here is an example for the [console logger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter), but even there I cannot see an easy way to get the Category as you want it (it is given in `LogEntry.Category` as string `"Foo"` already).

Comment: well I said type name, not parameter name, but I was struggling to find the correct term. question edited. thanks